# Results on continuity corrections

Tags: references, approximation

For me, the first thing that comes to mind when I come across the term *continuity correction* is that when $X\sim\mathrm{Bin}(n,p)$, one approximates $\Pr(X\le x)=\Pr(X<x)$ by $\Pr(Y<x+1/2)$ where $Y$ is normally distributed and has the same expectation and variance as $X$.  Of course one may also use continuity corrections with Poisson distributions, and among the automatic list of "Questions that may already have your answer", I find continuity corrections for Pearson and McNemar chi-square tests and Yates' continuity correction for $2\times2$ tables.

The fact that one gets reasonably close approximations even for fairly small $n$ is easily verified.  The fact that things work well as $n\to\infty$ is easy to see.

But what about precisely stated and proved mathematical results?  Those might include precise error bounds, things about rates of convergence, and other things.  What such results are known and where are they found?

Comment: Continuity corrections may apply pretty much any time you approximate discrete cdfs with continuous ones; as such the "general" results tend not to be very general. For example, even with something as standard as the normal approximation to the binomial, if $p\neq 0.5$, it's not necessarily an improvement; correction in the extreme tails can be worse than not correcting. For "smooth" unimodal situations, they often help a lot for ranges of probabilities near the mode, but the situation as you move further away seems to very much depend on circumstances. I'm unaware of any truly general results

Comment: There have been some papers look specifically at continuity corrections in the normal approximation to the binomial, but it's many years since I read one.