# Polychoric or Pearson correlations - pre-EFA analysis in R

Tags: r, correlation, factor-analysis, polychoric

I plan to run a series of exploratory factor analysis (EFA) models to investigate the factor structure of a scale in development using the R package `psych`. My *N* > 300 and each manifest variable (i.e., indicator/item) uses a 5-point Likert-type response option. Some items were reverse-coded (to my chagrin) but handled accordingly; there are no missing data. The structure of the data is as follows:

```
str(dat)
'data.frame':   315 obs. of  33 variables:
```

Given the scale's domain content (social science/higher ed), I presumed the data were ordinal, but I calculated both the Pearson and polychoric correlations (because science!) first:

```
library(psych)
library(GPArotation)
#library(corrplot)

corr_list = list(
    pearson = cor(dat), 
    poly = polychoric(dat)$rho)
```

When running polychoric correlations, a warning message is generated that states a *correction for continuity* was applied and `526` were adjusted ([see here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/295833/what-does-correct-for-continuity-mean)). I understand that polychoric correlations use a table of proportions and since some responses end up being empty, a correction is needed. My first question is with regard to this:

- Are the polychoric correlation coefficients [stable](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-93177-7) (p. 21) given that `526` cells were adjusted? This was a bit perturbing considering `dat` only has 315 obs -- OR is the solution adequate because the adjusted cells only account for about 5% of the overall data structure (315 rows * 33 variables = 10, 359 total cells)?

Different estimation methods for EFAs are available in the `psych` package, but the function also has an `arg` that requires a correlation call (e.g., `"cor"` [Pearson], `"poly"`, `"mixed"`, etc.); the type of correlation in conjunction with the estimation method can a drastic impact on the solutions provided, so I wanted to gain as much clarity about the correlation output as possible before moving forward. EFA follow-up on the horizon!